# нужно ли тире в предложении, где подлежащее местоимение и сущ

Tags: пунктуация

Он знаменитый актер, режиссер и продюсер.

Answer (score 1):

При подлежащем, выраженном личным местоимением, тире ставится:
а)если логическое ударение падает на подлежащее: Весь я — память, весь я — слух... (А. А. Блок)
Следовательно, вопреки основному правилу: "Тире между подлежащим, выраженным личным местоимением, и сказуемым, выраженным существительным, не ставится", Вы, Юля, можете поставить тире, если логически  выделяете подлежащее ОН.

Answer (score 0):

Он знаменитый актер, режиссер и продюсер.

Обычно в таких случаях (если подлежащее выражено местоимением) **тире не ставится,** так как логически выделено сказуемое, паузы нет.

Тире возможно в предложениях **с противопоставлением,** когда ударение падает на местоимение и делается пауза: Он  ― знаменитый актер, режиссер и продюсер, она ― известная актриса.

Comment: Простите! Исправьте, пожалуйста,  описку в слове "пауза", забавно получилось).

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина, у меня проблема на клавиатуре с буквой А.